# Is it okay to postpone an interview at Google?

Tags: hiring-process

So, I was recently invited to a job interview from a Google Recruiter after I applied to a SWE position.

I have read up about the overall process, and I have scheduled a first call with my recruiter tomorrow. (First Q: What can I expect in this first conversation, does anybody know?)
If all goes well, I am expecting to schedule a date for my first phone screen AFAIK. Then, the next step would be the on-site interview.

Which brings me to my main question - I feel like I have a decent chance to get a job offer, but only if I have more time to prepare. I am currently working on my Bachelor Thesis and on two other Uni courses and would need some extra time to properly prepare for the well-known algorithms & data structure interview that Google conducts.

Is it fair to ask my recruiter for a date 2 months in advance? Should I suck it up and power through? What is my best bet here?

Comment: No one here can tell how they would feel about such a request (crystalball.com:65500/clairvoyancy is currently out of service )..

Comment: It's likely that the job in question may be filled by the time you get around to being ready.  So no, it's probably not OK to postpone like this.

Comment: @jwh20, the upshot is Google is a very large company and is hiring pretty much constantly. There will probably be other openings by then.

Comment: @jwh20 they may have changed practice in the few years since I interviewed there; but at the time Google's software engineer interview was generic and the results were then internally shopped to teams needing new staff; not interviews for specific positions up front.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are overcomplicating things...

Phone screens are VERY basic.

Not something you should wait 2 months for. If it were me, if someone asked for 2 months, I'd discard their resume.

That, after i started writing before reading your whole post "would you really want to work for a company that discards good candidates for not being able to make a specific meeting date..."

In reality, if you need to push it back a few days or a week, that's normal. 1-2 months will sound ridiculous.

At almost any job.. the position will be 'filled' / selected well within 2 months (even if, of course, person does not start that quickly).

Lastly... **Stop valuing companies differently based on their name brand.** When you make decisions based differently 'because it's google', you are actively devaluing yourself and others, adding some kind of magic leverage to the company solely because it is a name brand.

For the same reasons you and others will then be convinced to accept lower pay 'for the experience' and 'fame' (in quotes because that's a joke to everyone else) of working at such a 'prestigious' company (again, quotes, a joke).

In actuality these organizations are the IT equivalent of a puppy mill - they hire hundreds, thousands of developers. They're not startups anymore and the things we all heard hyping them up at the start certainly aren't what they are today, and you need to look at them for what they are... a job. You're not working / interviewing 'for google'. you are interviewing for a job. They are interviewing a candidate. Don't start already behind on negotiating / mindset.

Comment: *"At almost any job.. the position will be 'filled' / selected well within 2 months (even if, of course, person does not start that quickly)."* I can't speak for Google but that's a bit of an exaggeration in the general case. There are companies and organizations that hire slowly.

Comment: Well, it's a big country, so i'm sure there are some companies that hire slowly.... but in this environment that would be a terrible thing. Every org I've ever worked with has generally finished hiring within a month or two. They might have a REQ open for months without a good candidate - but if they've got candidates, from what i've seen they are trying to get someone into that position quickly. I've even seen terribly underqualified people getting shoved into a role because the business needs someone and can't wait

Answer (score 0):

> Is it fair to ask my recruiter for a date 2 months in advance? Should I suck it up and power through? What is my best bet here?

Here's the problem. If you applied, and got the interview, then they're going to wonder why you applied if you don't have time. So they might think you're not serious and thus, put you on the bottom.

A large company like google doesn't just do one interview and say you're hired. Not trying to keep your hopes down, but truthfully everyone gets an interview at google. Doesn't mean they're hired.

My advice is to go to the recruiter interview. He's going to get a feel for what he can do for you and now is your best chance. My thought is during the recruiter screening process you can bid your situation:

> Hello, my name is X. I'm currently writing my thesis and taking two university courses and I feel I am prepared for the interview within X months. I am very excited to get a chance to work at google and feel I would be best suited with Y. Please take my resume.

The recruiter would say thank you, X. We'd be happy and just so you know we're looking to fill a position in X month's time and do you think you can do an on-site interview at that time?

And who knows. You miss all the shots you don't take and my advice is not to pass on something just because of your situation. Just go to the recruiter interview. It's just a screening process right now, but at an actual interview, you're going to need to put your game face on and really nail down on when you can start, and what can be done.

At best, you get an interview. At worst, you get some practice and feel on what sort of things you need to get a job.